# $A \oplus C = B \oplus C$ but $A\neq B$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, with subspaces $A, B,C$ such that $A\oplus C = B\oplus C = V$. Prove or give a counterexample disproving that $A=B$.

I am trying to find a counterexample.

Comment: Let A be the empty set, and B=C.

Comment: I made a correction to the question, but I think your solution still works with B=C=V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the subspaces $A$,$B$,$C$ all be lines in the same plane. $A\oplus B$ and $A\oplus C$ will be that plane, but $A$ and $B$ are different lines and so not equal.

So in fact this is untrue *very* generically. Because direct sums "fill out" more space than you started with, there isn't a unique way to break a subspace down into pieces, even if you specify almost all of them.